# converting form elements (inputs) to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, transform

is there a way to transform all inputs field to divs? or span or anything.
i have a table like:

```
<div id="calc">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Principal:</td>
<td><input value="100.00$" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>start date:</td>
<td><input value="02/02/2002" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>end date:</td>
<td><input value="02/02/2002" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and i want copy this source to a light box without inputs.. like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Principal:</td>
<td><div>100.00$</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>start date:</td>
<td><div>02/02/2002</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>end date:</td>
<td><div>02/02/2002</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i wonder is there a way to convert all those inputs to divs may be via using **.replace** or something else ?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#calc').clone().appendTo('#lightbox');
$('#lightbox input').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<div>' + $(this).val() + '</div>');
});
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/c9Rub/2/

Updated to include copying the content to another div with the ID lightbox.

Comment: personally I'd go for this  - return $('<div>').text($(this).val()) - to ensure that any HTML within the input fields doesn't get rendered.

Comment: Also, what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: its changing original html source. my content have a few  light box one of them calculating.. another one is for printing.. and i tried this but its effecting to original source.. i tried a few attraction on it but i received [object, object]

Comment: Check, the update. It will now copy the content to another div and then change it. You can replace #lightbox with whatever element ID you need.

Comment: now im trying : 

var a= $('#calc').html();
$("input",a).each(function(){
                this.outerHTML = "<div>" + this.value+ "</div>";
});

PrintPopUp(a)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not using any libs:

Here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp, you can find some useful functions to do this.

By getting the input elements that you need, something like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

You can replace them with this:

```
  //pseudo
  for each input element
    var parentNode = input.parentNode;
    parentNode.removeChild(input);
    parentNode.innerHTML('<div>' + input.value + '</div>');
```

In the link that I put above, you can find some functions either to replace child or either to findParent, remove the current child and then append your div by yourself.

Comment: oh sorry i forgat to say that im using jquery, i wrote it to tags but forgat to use on description.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you can do the following.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnChange").click(function () {
            $("#calc :input").each(function () {
                this.outerHTML = "<div>" + this.value+ "</div>";
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="calc">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Principal:</td>
<td><input value="100.00$" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>start date:</td>
<td><input value="02/02/2002" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>end date:</td>
<td><input value="02/02/2002" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnChange" value="Change" />
```

Comment: it effected to origianl content, but i was want to copy that content to another lightbox. InfernalBadger's solution worked.. thank you